# Hub-Spoke topology -- L3 Links use multiple /30s vs single /24 shared?

Tags: routing, design, layer3, point-to-point

I wanted to ask the community their thoguhts on the pros and cons of this scenario. I have a few L3 switches with their own independent VLANS connecting to a a set of stacked switches over a port-channel. My question is which is better, if knowing these spoke switches are stubs. Using Point-to-point /30 links between each spoke switch and the hub switch, or using a single /24 with the hub switch spanning a vlan across the ports used. I will also be using EIGRP towards our CORE and summarizing wherever possible.

Multipoint -- Multiple /30s 
[image]

Multipoint -- Single /24
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current design it's not going to be a huge difference. However, assuming that you would have the same management VLAN for the entire network and spanning lots of switches, the point to point links would be better for the following reasons:

- Smaller L2 domain size
- No bridging loop possible
- Easier troubleshooting

Because the layer 2 domain would be limited and each management VLAN would only span a pair of switches, any reachability issues would be easy to point out and find the origin of the problem.